Where did i put my directory?
I wanted to move my World file from my Terraria Server and used
(I was currently in the .local directory)
sudo mv share/ /terraria because
I wanted to move the share folder into the terraria directory. But now its completely gone. I cant find it anymore. I am pretty much a noob in Linux and thought it would work like this. Please help me, I fear to lose my worlds.

Sounds like you meant to do sudo mv share/ ./terraria and expected it to be in the .local directory?  Your directory is where you specified though, at /terraria

Okay I found it, I made a directory with the name terraria in my Root. Do you know how to move files into the ./local directory? because when I try it they aren't there. I need these files in there because the Terraria server grabs them from the ./local/share/terraria/worlds directory to start the Server.

mv /terrari /path/to/local/share/terraria  replace /path/to with the actual full path to that directory

sudo mv share/ /terraria moves the directory terraria to the root. The reason is, that you explicitly asked to put it there with the leading / before terraria.
If you want it to go to the current directory, don't put a leading / to it:
sudo mv share/ terraria

or specify the the full path where you want the terraria to go to.
